# Why tail command read non existing value from file?

Tags: shell, gdb, tail

I'm Using GDB. From the GDB, I'm trying to read the last line from a file. And put that into a variable and print it. Problem is when I read the last line from the file and print it, it shows something that doesn't exists in the original line.  My file name: **new_name** Contains the following lines,

```
"swapper"
"systemd"
"kthreadd"
"rcu_gp"
```

I use the following command to read the last line from **new_name** and print it

```
shell echo set \$last_name=$(tail -n 1 new_name) > gdb.tmp
source gdb.tmp

p $last_name
```

Above command print the following:

> "rcu_gp\000\000"

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening, and how to read the file content as it is?

Thank you.

Comment: why `shell echo set` ? you can do that with `last_name=$(tail -n1 new_name ); echo $last_name`

Comment: Can you tell us your OS and the output of `gdb --version | head -1` ? Also, if you run the shell command `cat -vet gdb.tmp`, does it show those 0 bytes (they'll show up as `^@`)?

Comment: @P.... as I said before, I'm running this command from inside the gdb. And without **shell echo set**, an error like ** No symbol "tail" in current context** pops up

Comment: @MarkPlotnick gdb --version | head -1 shows : GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git. No, the "cat -vet gdb.tmp" show this : set $last_name="rcu_gp"$

Comment: @perplex and if you copy-paste `set $last_name="rcu_gp"` into your gdb session, `p $last_name` works as expected?

Comment: @thatotherguy yes.

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu 18.04. I can't reproduce it on my 18.04 system. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, with the mentioned command, I can read everything above that  `rcu_gp` correctly. But that problem occurs out of nowhere